# ToolTip in bryntum scheduler

Tags: javascript, extjs, bryntum-scheduler

I am new to Extjs.  I am using the Bryntum scheduler in my application.

In that I want to show tooltip over scheduled item. I checked the Bryntum API and found that I can use `**tooltipTpl**` to show tooltip and `**tipCfg**` to configure it. I added `eventmouseenter` listener and in respective function I tried to add `tooltipTpl`

My listener is

> eventmouseenter: this.eventMouse

and eventMouse function is

```
function(e) {
        e.apply(e.tipCfg,
        {
            trackMouse: false      
        });
        var tooltipTpl = "My Tool Tip";
       e.apply(e,
        {
            tooltipTpl: tooltipTpl
        });
    }
```

but the code doesn't seems to work. Please help me out for using tootipTpl.

Comment: Have you tried `e.setTooltipTpl('My Tool Tip')`?

Comment: No @CD.. I haven't tried. thanks for your response. Let me check it out.

Comment: @CD.. it is also not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a listener, just use the `tooltipTpl` configuration on your Scheduler:

```
tooltipTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<span>My Tool Tip</span>'),
...
```

It can be a String as well:
http://www.bryntum.com/docs/scheduling/3.x/?#!/api/Sch.panel.SchedulerGrid-cfg-tooltipTpl

**Edit:** See the code of this example using tooltips: http://www.bryntum.com/examples/scheduler-latest/examples/performance/performance.html